# Use a dynamically-generated, random IV | SecureRandom unable to decrypt the encrypted values

Tags: secure-random

I'm working to fix a Sonar Vulnerability for "AES/CTR/NoPadding"  Algorithm. Existing code is using IV to encrypt and decrypt the data. IV is generated like this :

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding");

cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]));

but Sonar is complaining the above logic saying "Use a dynamically-generated, random IV".

When I tried Sonar suggestion  below  for encrypting and decrypting the data:

```
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
byte[] bytesIV = new byte[16];
    random.nextBytes(bytesIV);

    /* KEY + IV setting */
    IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(bytesIV);
```

To Encrypt :

```
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
byte[] bytesIV = new byte[16];
    random.nextBytes(bytesIV);
 Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(bytesIV));
                return  Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8")));
```

To Decrypt:

```
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
byte[] bytesIV = new byte[16];
    random.nextBytes(bytesIV);
 Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(bytesIV));

 return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(strToDecrypt)));
```

After this logic Sonar Vulnerability is fixed  and Encryption also fine but Problem was on Decryption as  IV is newly generated for for each time and encryption was with another IV so Decryption is not returning correct data.

How can I solve this issue ?

I have scenario where I have to encrypt the data in an application and save encrypted data in db and another application will decrypt it but as we used securerandom so always IV will be different and data will not decrypt correctly.

I have tried to append the IV  by converting base64 string to encrypted string and tried to use on decryption that IV but Sonar complaint  that can't  use constant to get byte array.

I have tried with RSA public and private key to encrypt and decrypt the data and that is working for fixed amount of data but I have to encrypt large  data file.

Appreciate in advance for solution......